# Ubuntu start is showing a dump message

Tags: restart

I am using Ubuntu 16.0 for my development work on my desktop and laptop both. I am facing an issue on both system since yesterday on restart. I see the error dump as shown in screenshot.

[image]

I tried multiple restarts to my system but I am still seeing same. Any help will be really appreciated.